# Application crashes when trying to open other activities using intent

Tags: java, android

can someone please help. I am trying to use three buttons on one activity, the first buttons works perfectly but the others don't, when i click the other button the app crashes. I have attached the code below for the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bplayer1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlayer2);
        TextView tvList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvList);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player1Activity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player2Activity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent2);
            }
        });

        tvList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent3);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show crash report?

Comment: The fact that it both compiles and crashes when you click on the last button tells me that you've wired up the event just fine.  The problem is likely either the creation of your myIntent3 or your call to startActivity with myIntent3 instance.

Comment: Please update your question and include the logcat exception stacktrace and code of your `ListActivity` class.

Comment: Check your your two class Player2Activity and ListActivity the error is not in MainActivity class. are the two class in same Package as MainActivity class?